# Hiding implementation to client

Tags: design-patterns

I am studying the design patterns and there are some things I don’t get to understand. 
For instance, I have often come across the idea of hiding the implementation to the client.

For example, with respect to the factory pattern I read that the logics of the application must not know the subclasses of the user interface, not even during the creation.

I don’t get why hiding the implementation to the client is an advantage. The only reason I can think of is that of simplicity. Indeed, I guess in this case the client needs to know only the interface, and not the various subclasses, in order to use the objects, thus making everything easier, since you don’t need to know the whole implementation of the subclasses. Am I right?

However, I think it might happen that you need to call a specific method of a subclass, in which case you are force to cast the subclass in order to call the method.

Having said that, I would like to ask you the following questions:

1. What does the idea of “hiding concrete classes or hiding the implementation to the client mean? What’s the advantage? Is it just a matter of simplicity and maintenance?

Moreover, I would like you to give me some advice on books and online resources (theory and practice) on software engineering. Indeed, there are several aspects of it which are unclear to me. Namely independent objects and programming to interface.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like this would be better asked here ... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KornMuffin when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Think about operating a car. All cars have more or less a standard interface: a key for unlocking and starting it, a control to say go forward or back, a control to accelerate and a control to brake. Now think about how many "concrete implementations" there are behind those interfaces? The "client" of a car when she's operating it doesn't need to know if it's a gasoline/electric/hybrid motor or if the engine is cooled by water or by air, etc. Because operators use the same controls despite different implementations, cars are interchangeable with operators.

Comment: thank you all for the answers, i'm reading head first design pattern, yes i get that hiding implementation, programming to interface and polymorphism are correlated.. hiding implementation means make object independents, and you can use the same operation for different subtype of the that interface..(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you are working for company A and you developed an API and made everything public. Other developers of the company in different locations and time zones used your API to develop their own applications. Your API is used by hundreds of others in 10 different projects. Since your code is used in a lot of places, you wanted to make it better. You developed faster algorithms and even reduced the line of code 20%. You happily committed your code on Friday evening and left. When you come to your office on Monday morning you will realize that you broke everybody else's code. People cannot compile their code because you have deleted or changed the code that they depend on. You will get a lot of angry e-mails and calls and eventually you will have to rollback your API to the previous version.

This is why you have to hide your implementation. Once it is public you cannot change that. Think about it what happens if Google changes a method name or return type of a method in Android SDK. They break thousands of applications. There is always a tension between API developers and users. Developers want to hide everything and users want to access everything. If you release a very small interface people will not use your API, if you expose a lot of implementation details you will not be able to change your code.

Users of an API should not worry or think about concrete classes. It is not their business it belongs to API developer. If you want to learn about it more you can read Effective Java and a Design Pattern book. I recommend Head first Design Patterns.